# android notification repeat

Tags: notifications

I'm using Google Pixel XL (OG) w/ latest Android OS w/ latest security update, yet noticing that Android sometimes shows me exact same notification as it showed me recently and I already swiped it out(

Please advise.

Comment: Did you get the same notifications after your restarted the device?

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal notifications repeat happens without reboot, just after I swipe out notification, exact same notification appears.